# Node js small learning app with file check problems and error catching

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to get my hands on Node.js and javascript in console. So I was doing a small app.
I have a phot file that i want to add watermark. All is good but i have two problems

1. I want to check if files exists. I am using fs.existsSync(). But my problem is that i also want to check if my watermark logo exists nad this part is tripping me. This is all done in addImageWatermarkToImage() where my watermark file is one of my arguments "watermarkFile"
2. Second problem is try catch. I want to catch error for my fs.existsSync()
3. My retry is not running after all saving is done.

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const fs = require('fs');

const addTextWatermarkToImage = async function(inputFile, outputFile, text) {
  const image = await Jimp.read(inputFile);
  const font = await Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK);
  const textData = {
    text: text,
    alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
    alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE,
  };
  image.print(font, 10, 10, textData, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
  image.quality(100).write(outputFile);
};

const addImageWatermarkToImage = async function(
  inputFile,
  outputFile,
  watermarkFile
) {
  const image = await Jimp.read(inputFile);
  const watermark = await Jimp.read(watermarkFile);
  const x = image.getWidth() / 2 - watermark.getWidth() / 2;
  const y = image.getHeight() / 2 - watermark.getHeight() / 2;

  image.composite(watermark, x, y, {
    mode: Jimp.BLEND_SOURCE_OVER,
    opacitySource: 0.5,
  });

  image.quality(100).write(outputFile);
};

const prepareOutputFilename = filename => {
  const [name, ext] = filename.split('.');
  return `${name}-with-watermark.${ext}`;
};

const startApp = async () => {
  //check if user is ready
  const answer = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      name: 'start',
      message:
        'Hi! This is "Watermar manager". Move your files to `/img` folder. Then you\'ll be able to use them in the app. Are you ready?',
      type: 'confirm',
    },
  ]);

  // if no - exit app
  if (!answer.start) process.exit();

  // ask about input file and watermark type
  const options = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      name: 'inputImage',
      type: 'input',
      message: 'What file do you want to mark?',
      default: 'test.jpg',
    },
    {
      name: 'watermarkType',
      type: 'list',
      choices: ['Text watermark', 'Image watermark'],
    },
  ]);
  if (options.watermarkType === 'Text watermark') {
    const text = await inquirer.prompt([
      {
        name: 'value',
        type: 'input',
        message: 'Type your watermark text:',
      },
    ]);
    options.watermarkText = text.value;
    if (fs.existsSync('./img/' + options.inputImage)) {
      addTextWatermarkToImage(
        './img/' + options.inputImage,
        './img/' + prepareOutputFilename(options.inputImage),
        options.watermarkText
      );
    } else {
      console.log('O_o Error!!!!');
    }
  } else {
    const image = await inquirer.prompt([
      {
        name: 'filename',
        type: 'input',
        message: 'Type your watermark name:',
        default: 'logo.png',
      },
    ]);
    options.watermarkImage = image.filename;
    if (fs.existsSync('./img/' + options.inputImage)) {
      addImageWatermarkToImage(
        './img/' + options.inputImage,
        './img/' + prepareOutputFilename(options.inputImage),
        './img/' + options.watermarkImage
      );
    } else {
      console.log('O_o Error!!!!');
    }
  }

  console.log('File was saved');

  const retry = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      name: 'retry',
      message: 'Do you want to try again',
      type: 'confirm',
    },
  ]);
  if (!retry.retry) process.exit();
  startApp();
};

startApp();
```

Comment: `fs.existsSync` returns true/false - so won't throw an error if nothing is found [link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

Comment: Okay got this part so far. Thanks. NOw need to get rest of this stuff right